# Opencart Currency Symbol Color Change

Tags: colors, opencart, currency

As above, im trying to change the color and size of the currency symbol in opencart, im noticing that the pricetitle the symbol and the amount has the same css added but i would like to modd just the currency symbol.. not the amount. any ideas how to do this? i cant find from where is that symbol "pulled inn"

its the default 1.5.4 theme

thanks in forwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol is pulled in from your configuration by `/system/library/currency.php`. You can edit your symbols under `SYSTEM > LOCALISATION > CURRENCY` in the admin area and could add a span with a class around the symbol then add a rule to your css file